# how to prevent the json data output being alphabetically sorted and stored in mysql work?

Tags: mysql, json

Hi I'm trying to insert complex json data in mysql workbench but my json data being inserted alphabetically sorted. How do I get json data with same order which I passed in insert query?

**Create table:**

```
CREATE TABLE payload ( `id` INT NOT NULL,
      `json` JSON NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

**Insert Json**

```
INSERT INTO payload ( id, json)
VALUES  (2, '{
    "request": "release",
    "type": [
        {
            "type" : 1
        }
    ],
    "start": [
        {
            "type": "sample",
            "id": "01",
            "content": [
                {
                    "name": "jon",
                    "email": "jon@gmail.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}');
```

**stored json in database after select * table name:**

```
'3', '{\"type\": [{\"type\": 1}], \"start\": [{\"id\": \"01\", \"type\": \"sample\", \"content\": [{\"name\": \"jon\", \"email\": \"jon@gmail.com\"}]}], \"request\": \"release\"}'
```

Actually I want to have store my json same as my inserted json in database.

Is there a way to prevent the json data being alphabetically sorted?

Thanks.

Comment: Why does the order of properties matter?

Comment: yes. I will read that json as input

Comment: @nancy The order of properties should not matter in json data type. If you want to preserve the order, then store it as a string. Retrieve it and convert it into json. But you will not be able to leverage the advantages of making it a json data type.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql will automatically sort the keys of a JSON object before it's stored.
I had the same problem!

The solution is to change the column type to 'text' and then the order of keys will not be changed!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use serialize before storing. The conversion will make the array unrecognizable to MySQL so when retrieved and restored with unserialize it will be in the exact same order as before storage.

The drawback is the native MySQL json functions and methods can't be used to search and manipulate the array. Serializing is good only for storing and retrieving.

The only other way is to add a key with a value representing the array's sort order. That drawback is that the array must be sorted to restore it to its original state.